# Why I am getting insufficient scope error by posting json through postman?

Tags: json, postman

I have added headers and token but still having **insufficient_scope** error by posting json through postman

Comment: Can you post the request you're submitting?

Comment: It's private data.

Comment: I'm sorry, but without a little more detail or an example, you're going to find it difficult to get much help.

Comment: without mentioning what url, what data its not possible to answer this . THe only thing that one could think of is that your token is assigned with lesser access. You might not have enough permissions to post that data

Comment: @ChrisAdams  Thank you for help. Yes , It was the issue regarding token. That has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You must share the details of request to get help.** But let me also try to help you out blindly.*

---

I had the same issue in the past and resolved it with some simple attempts.

1. Please make sure that your token is correct, it's not expired, and it's authorized to make requests and access the relevant resources from the calling API.
2. Also make sure to add `bearer` at the start of your token.

Hope it solves your related issue.

Comment: Thank you for your helping comment. Yes the issue has been resolved that was regarding token.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check your request method. (I just spent a good 30 minutes trying to figure out why I was failing.) If you have only the `listings_r` scope, then you can only `GET`. You must have `listings_w` to `POST`. (My problem was copy/pasting several lines of cURL code, and I assume someone else reading this may have done the same.)